# Using DistributionFitTest on custom distributions in Mathematica 8

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, version-8, distributions

I originally posted this question [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808111/using-distributionfittest-on-custom-distributions-in-mathematica-8), but I didn't get any answers, and I'm hoping to have better luck here.

---

I'm trying to compute the goodness-of-fit of a bi-modal Gaussian distribution.
To do this, Mathematica seems to require a symbolic distribution function to which to compare. Because such a bi-modal distribution is not a stock distribution, I'm trying to define one.

The obvious use of

```
MixtureDistribution[{fs, (1-fs),
  {NormalDistribution[μS, σS], NormalDistribution[μL, σL]}]
```

generates a distribution that can be plotted, but the analysis used by `DistributionFitTest[]` fails.

This topic has been addressed in previous questions in discussions between @Sasha and @Jagra:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361647/distributionfittest-for-custom-distributions-in-mathematica

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202531/minimizing-nexpectation-for-a-custom-distribution-in-mathematica?lq=1

but I was unable to find a resolution that enabled the use of

```
DistributionFitTest[data,dist,"HypothesisTestData"]
```

when `dist` is not a built-in distribution type.

Because the distribution I'm modeling is composed of simple pieces, describing the properties of the distribution is not too difficult, and I have attempted to describe as many features as I know in order to create a well defined distribution that *Mathematica* 8 would recognize as one of its own. My attempt to define every parameter I can think of follows:

```
modelDist /: 
PDF[modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_], x_] :=
PDF[MixtureDistribution[{fS, 1 - fS}, {NormalDistribution[μS, σS], NormalDistribution[μL, σL]}], x];

modelDist /: 
CDF[modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_], x_] :=
CDF[MixtureDistribution[{fS, 1 - fS}, {NormalDistribution[μS, σS], NormalDistribution[μL, σL]}], x];

modelDist /: 
DistributionDomain[modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_]] := 
Interval[{-Infinity, Infinity}];

modelDist /: 
Random`DistributionVector[modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_], n_, prec_] := 
RandomVariate[MixtureDistribution[{fS, 1 - fS}, {NormalDistribution[μS, σS], NormalDistribution[μL, σL]}], n, WorkingPrecision -> prec];

modelDist /: 
DistributionParameterQ[modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_]] := 
!TrueQ[Not[Element[{fS, μS, σS, μL, σL}, Reals] && fS > 0 && fS < 1 && σS > 0 && σL > 0]];

modelDist /: 
DistributionParameterAssumptions[modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_]] := 
Element[{fS, μS, σS, μL, σL}, Reals] && fS > 0 && fS < 1 && σS > 0 && σL > 0;

modelDist /: 
MomentGeneratingFunction[modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_], t_] := 
fS E^(t μS + (t^2 σS^2)/2) + (1 - fS) E^(t μL + (t^2 σL^2)/2);

modelDist /: 
CharacteristicFunction[modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_], t_] := 
fS E^(I t μS + (t^2 σS^2)/2) + (1 - fS) E^(I t μL + (t^2 σL^2)/2)

modelDist /: 
Moment[modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_], n_] := 
Piecewise[{{fS*σS^n*(-1 + n)!!*Hypergeometric1F1[-(n/2), 1/2, -(μS^2/(2*σS^2))] + (1 - fS) * σL^n*(-1 + n)!! * Hypergeometric1F1[-(n/2), 1/2, -(μL^2/(2*σL^2))], Mod[n, 2] == 0}}, μS*σS^(-1 + n)*n!!* Hypergeometric1F1[(1 - n)/2, 3/2, -(μS^2/(2*σS^2))] + (1 - fS) * μL*σL^(-1 + n)*n!! * Hypergeometric1F1[(1 - n)/2, 3/2, -(μL^2/(2*σL^2))]];

modelDist /: 
Mean[modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_]] := 
fS μS + (1 - fS) μL

modelDist /: 
Expectation[expr_, x_ \[Distributed] modelDist[fS_, μS_, σS_, μL_, σL_]] := 
fS*Expectation[expr, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μS, σS]] + (1 - fS)*Expectation[expr, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μL, σL]]
```

Everything seems to work up through the definition of Expectation, which throws

> TagSetDelayed::tagpos: Tag modelDist in Expectation[expr_, x_\[Distributed]modelDist[fS_, \μS_, \σS_, \μL_, \σL_]] is too deep for an assigned rule to be found.

I don't know that having a definition for the expectation will magically make everything work, but it's the next step to to try, as having the expectation allows computation of the variance, and for all I know, that is the last tag that I need to define. Is there a syntax that will properly define this `Expectation` in such a way that the expression will pass straight from my `modelDist` to its constituent `NormalDistribution`s?

(And if this entirely the wrong way to go about this, some advice to that effect would be appreciated.)

Comment: I wonder if you could run the distribution fit tests individually?  It might help narrow down what doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer but too long for a comment. This works for me in versions 8.0.4 and 9.0.0.

```
dist = 
  modelDist[fS, μS, σS, μL, σL] /. 
   FindInstance[
     DistributionParameterAssumptions[
      modelDist[fS, μS, σS, μL, σL]], 
         {fS, μS, σS, μL, σL}, Reals][[1]];

DistributionFitTest[RandomVariate[dist, 100], dist]

(* 0.846971 *)
```

It isn't necessary for `Expectation` to work for `DistributionFitTest` to do its job.  `DistributionFitTest` does need `CDF` to be defined which you have done.

Comment: This generates a specific instance of `modelDist`, but it doesn't find the parameters `fS,\[Mu]S`, etc., that best fit a data sample.  This is possible using `htd=DistributionFitTest[RandomVariate[dist,100],NormalDistribution[\[Mu],\[Sigma]], "HypothesisTestData"`, even if the uni-modal fit doesn't match the bimodal distribution.  `htd` will contain best fit values for `\[Sigma]` and `\[Mu].`  However, I can't figure out how to plug `modelDist` directly into `DistributionFitTest` so that I can get estimates and confidence intervals for `fS,\[Mu]S,\[Sigma]S,\[Mu]L`, and `\[Sigma]L`.

Comment: This is much more complicated. When estimating the parameters from the data itself the test is no longer valid (unless a correction factor has been added for that distribution with estimated parameters which it hasn't). You can still use `EstimatedDistribution` to get the maximum likelihood estimate if that is what you are after but the test on the resulting distribution is still not valid. You will need to resort to other methods such as quantile plots etc.

Comment: What I'm after in this instance is the "plug-n-play"-ness of  being able to drop a set of data into `DistributionFitTest` against a model distribution with variable parameters.  If the distribution I was trying to fit was more complicated, I might give up, but it's just the sum of two gaussians.  It seems this should be very straightforward, and I'd happily specify all behaviors by hand in order to get `DistributionFitTest` to work in this fashion, as it does with the "native" _Mathematica_ distributions.  However, I don't know what is needed in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [image]

or try

```
edist=EstimatedDistribution[data,MixtureDistribution[{p,1-p},{GammaDistribution[a1,b1],GammaDistribution[a2,b2]}]]//Quiet
```